# Create Mega Menu on OOTB structural navigation in SharePoint 2013 on Premise

Tags: jquery, navigation, sharepoint-2013, megamenu

I want to create Mega Menu in SharePoint 2013 on premise.

Mega menu which i want to implement it should be using OOTB structural navigation.
I have gone through most of the articles, but the problem is most of the articles either maintain the navigation data in List or create custom HTML & applied J query or CSS.

I want solution which I can applied direct to the SharePoint OOTB top navigation.

I am new to the SharePoint branding.

Please help me out with this.

Thanks!!!!!

Comment: For the navigation you should use oob Managed Navigation: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn194311.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 as for the branding part CSS/HTML/JS will be required

Comment: Thanks nizzik Yeah I Know but the requirement is to use only structural navigation.